# Giff LZW compression

Tags: image, gif, lzw

http://giflib.sourceforge.net/whatsinagif/lzw_image_data.html

I was reading this page to understand Giff's LZW compression. It shows encoded codes from its sample image:

#4 #1 #6 #6 #2 #9 #9 ..

After variable length compressing into bytes, it becomes:

8C 2D 99 ..

which means:

#4 - 3 bits

#1 - 3 bits

#6 - 3 bits

#6 - 3 bits

#2 - 4 bits

#9 - 4 bits

This compressed image data is correct as I generated the giff sample image using Photoshop and verified binary content.

It clearly shows the bit size increase happens when output code #2

However, this is how the page talks about the bit size increase:
`When you are encoding the data, you increase your code size as soon as your write out the code equal to 2^(current code size)-1`

`Jumping back to our sample image, we see that we have a minimum code size value of 2 which means out first code size will be 3 bits long. Out first three codes, #1 #6 and #6, would be coded as 001 110 and 110. If you see at Step 6 of the encoding, we added a code of #7 to our code table. This is our clue to increase our code size because 7 is equal to 2^3-1 (where 3 is our current code size). Thus, the next code we write out, #2, will use the new code size of 4 and therefore look like 0010.`

But in its encoding table, step 6 is where entry #7 is added to LZW dictionary, but the code added for output is the first #6. According to the algorithm, the two #6 should be 4 bits each, but how come they are actually 3 bits?

according to this page 
https://www.eecis.udel.edu/~amer/CISC651/lzw.and.gif.explained.html

it says the same thing about bit size `If you're encoding, you start with a compression size of (N+1) bits, and, whenever you output the code (2**(compression size)-1), you bump the compression size up one bit`

so what is wrong??

Comment: It's hard to follow the example without seeing the actual code table being built, but it's clear that the code width must increase as soon as there would be an opportunity for the next code to be output to overflow the current width, but not sooner. So, if the width does not increase where the description says it would need to, but if decompression still works, it must be because the algorithm has logic to detect that the new code added (which would overflow the current width) could not in fact occur in the output stream quite yet.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the example given on the page you linked to once again: The image has 4 colors only, i.e. the LZW compressor starts out with 3-bit codes. The dictionary contains 6 entries so far: the literals 0..3, the clear code 4, and the EOI code 5. The first two codes output are the clear code 4 and the literal 1. That's the way all GIF LZW streams start. Now compression begins, because the image starts with a run of 1's. After 2 more codes written to the stream, the 8 dictionary slots are exhausted, and the code size is increased to 4. So the next code - the literal 2 - is written as a 4-bit number.

As you see, nothing is wrong. That's just the way GIF works wit a 4-color image.